# Objective-C Download PLIST and use within table

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I'm fairly new to Objective-C programming. I'm trying to build an app for personal use to view event info which is contained on my web server. I wish for each Event Title string to be shown as a separate row within my UITableView.

I'm using [CFPropertyList](https://github.com/rodneyrehm/CFPropertyList) to create the plist from MySQL. Here's what my plist looks like:
[image]

I'm downloading the plist like so:

```
NSString *stringURL = @"http://www.example.com/events.plist";
        NSURL  *url = [NSURL URLWithString:stringURL];
        NSData *urlData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
        if ( urlData )
        {
            NSArray       *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
            NSString  *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

            NSString  *filePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@", documentsDirectory,@"events.plist"];
            [urlData writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];
        }
```

Then this is how I'm trying to load the info into their arrays:

```
    events = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:filePath];

    ID = [events objectForKey:@"Event ID"];
    title = [events objectForKey:@"Event Title"];
    date = [events objectForKey:@"Event Date"];
    price = [events objectForKey:@"Price"];
    totalTickets = [events objectForKey:@"Total Tickets"];
    ticketsSold = [events objectForKey:@"Tickets Sold"];
    ticketsRemaining = [events objectForKey:@"Tickets Remaining"];
    postStatus = [events objectForKey:@"Post Status"];
    postContent = [events objectForKey:@"Post Content"];
```

Now here's where I'm having trouble. Now when I'm debugging the number of rows the 'events' dictionary has it returns 0.

Therefore I cannot set the 'numberOfRowsInSection'. Nor does `[title objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]` work.

I believe the issue lays with how I'm setting up the NSDictionary, but due to my lack of Objective-C and array knowledge, I'm unable to overcome this issue.

Comment: Please check if you are first storing the file correctly in your documentsDirectory

Comment: what is "title"? is it an array or string? looks string to me, so you can't call `[title objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]`

Comment: Hi, yes it's storing correctly. I can see it in the appdata. The "title" is an array.

Comment: Title is not an array. the value to the key `Event title` is a string. hence `[events objectForKey:@"Event Title"];` will return an NSString. so even if you typed the variable title as NSArray, you are assigning a NSString to it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's your problem:

```
events = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
```

Your plist is an array of dictionaries and you're trying to load that array as a dictionary. Try this instead:

```
events = [NSArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
```

**Edit:** To extract the titles into an array so you can use them in table cells, do this:

```
NSMutableArray *titles = [NSMutableArray array];
for (NSDictionary *event in events) {
    NSString *title = [event objectForKey:@"Event Title"];
    [titles addObject:title];
}
```

Comment: To add to this you'll then need to go through the array with a for loop: `for(int i=0;i<events.count;i++)` and to access the individual event you can call `NSDictionary *event = (NSDictionary*)[events objectAtIndex:i];` You can then access the values in the way you have attempted above

Comment: Hi Neil, that seems to work thanks. I can now get the correct number of events. However, one problem, Now how can I then put all of the 'title's into an array to use for the cell text? title = [events objectForKey:@"Event Title"] doesn't work when title is an array or dictionary. I get: -[__NSCFArray objectForKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Comment: @hart1994 I'll add that to my answer above.

Comment: @neilco now your answer is complete thats why i voteUp your answer

Comment: @neilco Thanks for this. It now displays the event title within each row, which is great. However, when scrolling down the list - it crashes with this error: *** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x16eabac0 I have been trying to overcome this issue. I believe it's due to a range exception, but I don't know how to fix. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Oops, after some hair pulling, I've finally figured it out. I wasn't retaining my NSMutableArray & releasing it. Thanks for all of your help!

Comment: @hart1994 No worries :) Glad you've got it sorted.